# Example: Enumerated Types ("JavaScript, O'Reilly Publishing")

Tags: javascript, enumerated-types

Has anyone read "JavaScript, The Definitive Guide" (O'Reilly)?

I spent several hours digesting Example 9-7.

In particular, the .foreach() "class" method has me somewhat puzzled.

Also, does .valueOf get called automatically?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the example given in the book (because 'Example 9-7' is meaningless to anyone who hasn't read it) and go into more detail on what confuses you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, does .valueOf get called automatically?

`valueOf` and `toString` are called "automatically". `valueOf` if the object i question is converted to a number, and `toString`, well, if it is converted to a string.

```
function Foo(){}

Foo.prototype = {
  constructor: Foo,
  valueOf: function() { return 2; },
  toString: function () { return 'bar' }
}

var f = new Foo();
f + f + 2 //6
'' + f   //"bar"
```

But if you would have read the book, you should know that already.

> In particular, the .foreach() "class" method has me somewhat puzzled.

Why? It is a member of `Array.prototype`, well documented and extremly handy. Or do you refering to another example?

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way you can use the `forEach` like this:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];

a.forEach(function(number) {
  console.log(number);
});
```

You don't have to use something like `valueOf`, the parameter of that function is already the value itself.